# Remove everything before a delimiter when not all cells contain that delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have a dataframe with a 'timezone' column. Some of the entries are listed as 'country/city'. I want them to just be 'city'. There were similar questions on stackoverflow, from which I came up with the following.

```
df['timezone'] = df['timezone'].str.split('/').str[1]
```

However, this deleted the entries without a '/' in. So I tried various other adaptations but couldn't get any to work.

Next I tried to construct a lambda function and use map, doing various adaptions of below, this didn't work either.

```
df['timezone'] = df['timezone'].map(lambda x: x.split('/').str[1]) 

#AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Finally, I decided to write a loop, below. Python took a while working through it, I was hopeful, but in the end nothing seemed to happen.

```
x = df['timezone']

for entry in x.items() :
    if x.str.contains('/') is True:
        x.str.split('/').str[1] 
        update(x) 
    else:
        pass
```

Any help or advice much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restrict the number of splits to `1` (required when the delimiter could occur more than once), and then use `str[-1]` instead of `str[1]`:

```
df   
       timezone
0  country/city
1           foo
2           bar

df['timezone'] = df['timezone'].str.split('/', n=1).str[-1]
df

  timezone
0     city
1      foo
2      bar
```

`str[-1]` adequately handles those cases where there was nothing to split on.

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED Thanks so much. Haha One of those OMG moments, all that extra (attempted) problem solving when all I needed was a minus! it even worked without n=1. Cheers